# Playfair cipher random key (C#)

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

Need to solve playfair code with shotgnhillclimbing method, Want to do it simple first by generating random key, and then calculating the score by english-book alphabet pair freq.

But I don't know how to produce nonrepeating random key, it's 25! possibilities. so if i use while forever, the possibility of me finding the right key is super small.

How can i produce a key and then ask the compiler to not to use it again?. Do i use list:add or remove? or is there anything else? or probably a string[25!]?

Comment: 25! is about 2^83, which is approximately the same number of calculations required to find a SHA-1 collission, so you are correct in not taking the brute force route :) I would advise against greating that string too, you would run out of atoms to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to start with a random key, then modify it at each step. Modifications you can perform include: swap two key letters, swap two entire rows, swap two entire columns, reflect around the middle column, reflect around the middle row, or reflect around either of the two major diagonals. At each step you randomly choose both a type of modification and a location for the modification.

It's possible that your random choice has no effect on the key matrix. For instance, if you choose to swap two rows, and select the same two rows for both operands of the swap, the key matrix will remain unchanged. That's fine. It is also possible that two successive operations will invert each other, thus returning the key matrix to its prior state. That's fine, too. Because each decision is made at random, some improving the key matrix, some making it worse, your hill-climbing algorithm will work perfectly well (though it may take a few more steps than necessary).

The point is that the probability of a repeating random key is fairly low, and it doesn't much matter if it does happen.